# Mysql convert from human date and time to usual timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, select, date-formatting

Is it possible to convert in MySql

```
June 15 2018 8:00 AM
```

to timestamp

```
2018-06-15 20:00:00
```

Using some preg_replace steps I can make June 15 2018 8:00 AM like

```
06-15-2018 8:00 AM
```

but anyway I need

```
2018-06-15 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd parse the string to a date using [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and then format it to the right representation with [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('June 15 2018 8:00 AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i %p'), 
                   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```